# GPUImage Multiple Input Filters

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I have recently encountered an issue I need help with, I have noticed if you use GPUImageTwoInputFilter or GPUImageThreeInputFilter, in a GPUImageFilterGroup, and apply that to GPUImagePicture's processImageUpToFilter, the resulting image is Nil.

I have traced the problem to GPUImageFilter's newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput method, specifically following lines of code

```
if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(imageCaptureSemaphore, convertedTimeout) != 0) { return NULL; }
```

the filter group I used is setup like

```
GPUImagePicture -> Crop Filter -> Custom GPUImageFilterGroup which has a GPUImageThreeInputFilter -> Output
```

I first thought that it could be issue in my custom filter, but it is also true in the GPUImageSoftEleganceFilter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
filterGroup = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter alloc] init];
filter1.temperature = 12000.0f;
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:filter1]; 

GPUImageGammaFilter *filter2 = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];
filter2.gamma = 1.0f;
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup addFilter:filter2];

[filter1 addTarget:filter2]; 

[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filter1]];
[(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filterGroup setTerminalFilter:filter2];
```